# Added a product with weight 220LB to the cart, proceed to checkout, but the Shipping methods are not showing up

Tags: cart, shipping-methods, product-weight

Using Magento 2.3.1

Added a product with weight 220LB to the cart ( the cart weight > 200lb ), proceed to checkout, but the Shipping methods are not showing up. 
There is no restriction for shipping methods. 
Shipping methods FLAT RATE, STORE PICKUP, UPS, CANADA POST are configured.

UPS & CANADA POST CARRIES have weight restriction but, FLAT RATE, STORE PICKUP has no restriction, though these methods are not displaying.

Please help to find the solution.

Comment: Is it a simple product? Have you tried setting the weight as 1lb?

Comment: It's a Simple Product. I have tried setting the weight 1LB, displays shipping methods. Thank you.

Comment: So you agree it's weight related?

Comment: Yes, if I change the weight of the cart to lower, shipping methods are displaying.

Comment: Are any of your shipping extensions you use custom? Or are you using the default extensions?

Comment: I have brought store pickup and Canada post extensions. but remaining I am using the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments it is a weight issue.

I believe either the store pickup or Canada post extension is causing this issue.

As the issue is easy to recreate I would reach out to the develops of the extensions.  Show them the problem you are experiencing and see if they can determine whether or not their extension is the cause.

Comment: Yes, Problem with the Canada post extension. Thank you.